# How to disable submit button if the required fields are empty in tcomb-form-native?

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I'm using tcomb-form-native and able to disable error messages on click of login button. Also on click of login button i'm routing it to next page i.e home page. I want to disable login button if the required fields are empty and enable it and redirect to home page when both the fields are filled. Below is the code which I tried.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Linking,
  Alert,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';

const Form = t.form.Form;

// here we are: define your domain model
const Email = t.subtype(t.Str, (email) => {
  const reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return reg.test(email);
});

const LoginFields = t.struct({
  username: Email,  // a required string
  password: t.String, // a required string
});

const options = {
  fields: {
    password: {
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Password',
      error: 'Password cannot be empty'
    },
    username: {
      placeholder: 'e.g: abc@gmail.com',
      error: 'Insert a valid email'
    }
  }
}; // optional rendering options (see documentation)


export default class Login extends Component {
  _onSubmit() {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
     if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
       console.log(value);
        // value here is an instance of LoginFields
     }

     this.props.navigator.push({
       id: 'Home'
     });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.contentHeader}>
            Pateast Login
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.loginFormContent}>
            <Form
              ref="form"
              type={LoginFields}
              options={options}
            />
              <Text style={{color: 'blue', marginBottom: 10}}
                onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.co.in')}>
                Forgot Password?
              </Text>
              <Button
                  onPress={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}
                  title="Login"
                  color="#008080"
                  accessibilityLabel="Ok, Great!"
                />
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
        </View>
      </View>


    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    contentHeader: {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 40,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginBottom: 30
    },
    header : {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    content: {
      flex: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    loginFormContent: {
      marginHorizontal: 20
    },
    footer: {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    loginText: {
      fontSize: 20,
      marginBottom: 10
    },
    inputFields: {
      fontSize: 20,
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      borderRadius: 30,
      marginBottom: 10
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: submit button is a separate component it has nothing to do with tcomb form, use [disabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#disabled) props of Button to achieve your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial state of disabled prop should be **true**
Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Linking,
  Alert,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';

const Form = t.form.Form;

// here we are: define your domain model
const Email = t.subtype(t.Str, (email) => {
  const reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return reg.test(email);
});

const LoginFields = t.struct({
  username: Email,  // a required string
  password: t.String, // a required string
});

const options = {
  fields: {
    password: {
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Password',
      error: 'Password cannot be empty'
    },
    username: {
      placeholder: 'e.g: abc@gmail.com',
      error: 'Insert a valid email'
    }
  }
}; // optional rendering options (see documentation)


export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonState: true,
      value: {}
    }
  }

  _onSubmit() {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
     if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
       console.log(value);
        // value here is an instance of LoginFields
     }

     this.props.navigator.push({
       id: 'Home'
     });
  }

  onChange = () => {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    if(value) {
      this.setState({
        value,
        buttonState: false
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.contentHeader}>
            Pateast Login
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.loginFormContent}>
            <Form
              ref="form"
              type={LoginFields}
              options={options}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
              <Text style={{color: 'blue', marginBottom: 10}}
                onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.co.in')}>
                Forgot Password?
              </Text>
              <Button
                  onPress={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}
                  title="Login"
                  color="#008080"
                  disabled={this.state.buttonState}
                  accessibilityLabel="Ok, Great!"
                />
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
        </View>
      </View>


    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    contentHeader: {
      // fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 40,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginBottom: 30
    },
    header : {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    content: {
      flex: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    loginFormContent: {
      marginHorizontal: 20
    },
    footer: {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    loginText: {
      fontSize: 20,
      marginBottom: 10
    },
    inputFields: {
      fontSize: 20,
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      borderRadius: 30,
      marginBottom: 10
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Linking,
  Alert,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';

const Form = t.form.Form;

// here we are: define your domain model
const Email = t.subtype(t.Str, (email) => {
  const reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return reg.test(email);
});

const LoginFields = t.struct({
  username: Email,  // a required string
  password: t.String, // a required string
});

const options = {
  fields: {
    password: {
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Password',
      error: 'Password cannot be empty'
    },
    username: {
      placeholder: 'e.g: abc@gmail.com',
      error: 'Insert a valid email'
    }
  }
}; // optional rendering options (see documentation)


export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     enabledButton: false,
     formValue: {
       email: '',
       password: '', // you need to check this well and update it when value changes
     },
   };
  }

   onChange(obj) {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    if (value) {
     this.setState({
      enabledButton: true,
     });
    } else {
     this.setState({
      enabledButton: false,
    });
   }
  }
  _onSubmit() {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
     if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
       console.log(value);
        // value here is an instance of LoginFields
     }

     this.props.navigator.push({
       id: 'Home'
     });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.contentHeader}>
            Pateast Login
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.loginFormContent}>
            <Form
              ref="form"
              type={LoginFields}
              options={options}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.formValue}
            />
              <Text style={{color: 'blue', marginBottom: 10}}
                onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.co.in')}>
                Forgot Password?
              </Text>
              <Button
                  onPress={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}
                  title="Login"
                  color="#008080"
                  accessibilityLabel="Ok, Great!"
                  disabled={this.state.enabledButton}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
        </View>
      </View>


    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    contentHeader: {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 40,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginBottom: 30
    },
    header : {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    content: {
      flex: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#f8f8ff',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    loginFormContent: {
      marginHorizontal: 20
    },
    footer: {
      flex: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: '#008080'
    },
    loginText: {
      fontSize: 20,
      marginBottom: 10
    },
    inputFields: {
      fontSize: 20,
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      borderRadius: 30,
      marginBottom: 10
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I'm getting unexpected token error near line 51 (onChange function). Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's not allowing me to write anything and button is still enabled. :(

Comment: because you need to set value for form , check my updated answer but it's not the complete solution you'll need to update value on change